# Hector to do incrementCounter for the subcolumn of a super cf

Tags: cassandra, hector

Currently the mutator seems only works against standard cf. Is there any other approach to go with to do incrementCounter on a subcolumn of a super cf?

Comment: I looked at the test cases on github, didn't find anything related. The basic idea that I have is to have counters by month for each, say, user. By doing so, one way is to create super column family key'd by user id, super column to be timestamp, and then sub columns to be counters. The Cassandra wiki said that it's supported, but I found no way to do so with Hector APIs so far. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little piece of code to increment counters of a superColumn

With SuperColumns with String keys, supernames and names...

```
String key = "keyOfRow"; 
    String superColumnFamily = "foo"; 
    String superColumnName ="bar"; 
    StringSerializer ss = StringSerializer.get(); 
    // let's insert a couple of counter columns in a superColumn 
    String columnName1="aaa"; 
    String columnName2="bbb"; 
    List <HCounterColumn<String>> myCounters = new 
ArrayList<HCounterColumn<String>>(); 
    myCounters.add(HFactory.createCounterColumn(columnName1, 1L)); 
    myCounters.add(HFactory.createCounterColumn(columnName2, 42L)); 
    Mutator mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, 
StringSerializer.get()); 
    mutator.insertCounter(key,superColumnFamily , 
HFactory.createCounterSuperColumn(superColumnName, myCounters, ss, 
ss)); 
mutator.execute();
```